# Find Google Tag Manager tag by console error

Tags: javascript

I need some help.
I've got error message in the dev tools console about a google tagmanager script and I don't know how to find the tag about the error message.

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getAttribute')
    at <anonymous>:1:83
    at <anonymous>:1:450
    at gtm.js?id=GTM-M24CZ7:458
    at gtm.js?id=GTM-M24CZ7:459
    at gtm.js?id=GTM-M24CZ7:459
    at c (gtm.js?id=GTM-M24CZ7:460)
    at jf (gtm.js?id=GTM-M24CZ7:86)
    at e (gtm.js?id=GTM-M24CZ7:208)
    at gtm.js?id=GTM-M24CZ7:37
    at Array.<anonymous> (gtm.js?id=GTM-M24CZ7:209)
```

Comment: If you follow the error this will most likely take you to a custom HTML tag on GTM. It might be best to look which custom code it is linked to and contact their support for help.